# Check if external storage Manager is granted for ANOTHER app

Tags: android, permissions, android-external-storage, android-11

I need to check if another app has the permission to External Storage Manager. With

```
Environment.isExternalStorageManager()
```

I check if the current app is granted. How can I do this for another app? I already tried to check the permission status with

```
getPackageManager().checkPermission(Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, "dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite")
```

but it return always -1, which means PERMISSION_DENIED, even if the permission is granted.

Comment: Why did your try fail?

Comment: Because checkPermission return -1 even if the permission is set for the package. Thank you for the question

Comment: What does -1 mean?

Comment: PERMISSION_DENIED

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using [AppOpsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager#OPSTR_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) class like this :

```
try {
        PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo info = packageManager.getApplicationInfo("package name",0);
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: "+hasPermission(this,info)); 
        
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now the `hasPermission` function :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
public static boolean hasPermission(Context context,ApplicationInfo info) {
    boolean granted = false;
    AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    int mode = appOps.unsafeCheckOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.permissionToOp("android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"), info.uid, info.packageName);
    if (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_DEFAULT)
        granted = (context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    else
        granted = (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
    return granted;
}
```

You also have to declare `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

Comment: @tijo I just tested this solution, it worked for me, you may consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

Here are more generalized version of DrHowdyDoo's solution

```
fun isExternalStorageManager(
    packageName: String,
    context: Context,
    packageManger: PackageManager
): Boolean {
    return hasPermission(packageName, MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, context, packageManger)
}


fun hasPermission(
    packageName: String,
    permission: String,
    context: Context,
    packageManger: PackageManager
): Boolean {
    val granted: Boolean
    val appOps = context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager

    val info = packageManger.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0)
    val mode = appOps.unsafeCheckOpNoThrow(
        AppOpsManager.permissionToOp(permission)!!,
        info.uid,
        packageName
    )
    granted = if (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_DEFAULT) {
        context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission) == PERMISSION_GRANTED
    } else {
        (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED)
    }

    return granted
}
```

Example:

```
isExternalStorageManager("dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite", this, getPackageManager())
```

You can also add the queried package like this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite" />
</queries>
```